# Does over-watering drown grubs?

Tags: watering, desert, grubs

I've been having a white grub (< 1 cm in size)

[image: white grub larva]

issue with the root system of a fruit tree. Is it possible, in an arid climate, to drown the grubs by watering the tree more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, over watering will not control 'grubs'.  You just have to send pictures of these grubs, fruit trees...  Where is it that you live?  Do NOT overwater.  Allow the birds to eat these grubs, the moles, the voles, the shrews...need to know exactly what insect with which you are dealing.  Get a big bowl or bucket of water and squirt a bunch of dish soap into it.  Swish it around and then dump it on one square foot of area on your lawn, a flat area.

Count the number of grubs that come up out of that spot of soil.  Take pictures of these grubs.  Then we will be able to guide you better.  Lots of people have made the mistake to use pesticide to kill 'grubs'...kills everything even the organisms designed to keep 'grubs' in check.  The next year their entire lawn is completely decimated.  Do not use pesticides.

Send more information and pictures...thanks!

[grub](https://guzmansgreenhouse.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/grubs-in-ground.jpg)

Grins!  Gotta see a picture of YOUR grubs, your tree, the trunk of your tree at the soil line.  Grubs are larvae of many insects.  This larval stage is extremely destructive by SOME types of larva in some types of environments.  Nice drawing but we gotta see the real dude to even get close to understanding your problem to be able to give you clearer answers.

You live in the SW Desert, you have a Mission Fig and somewhere near this tree you've been finding grubs.  Please send actual pictures.  Have you seen these grubs before in prior years?  Have you talked with your neighbors?

I would call your U of A Extension Service...cooperative extension service.  Fabulous help, pretty much free, master gardeners right there to help you with stuff they've probably seen.

Grubs can be very destructive, depending on their ID and life cycle.

Everyone needs to learn about this incredible service every state has access to...hosted by the main University of the State.  On this site we love to ID but I gotta tell you IDing by photos is iffy. I am amazed what most of these professionals on this garden and landscaping site are able to do for ID just by photos.

Photos are necessary at a minimum to do any ID's.  Ideally, one is able to hold, touch, smell, see the real plant, in its habitat.  Have the ability to use a specimen microscope...call up their favorite entomologist friend to confirm the ID of a grub.

Send more pictures...we most certainly can help with more info and pictures!

Is this grub as big and fat as yours?  This is a grub in the SW near a Mission Fig believe it or not.

Comment: I've updated my question. (Also, the type of fruit tree is a mission fig and it's grown in the southwest U.S.)

Comment: Mine are <1 cm in size.

Comment: "_Have you talked with your neighbors?_" The issue is localized to where I planted this particular mission fig tree, so I think the grubs came from the nursery.

Comment: Is the grub image you posted the normal size for a white grub?

Comment: Not so much, Geremia.  That is one heck of a grub...there are millions of types of grubs, literally, millions.  We need a picture of YOUR grub so we can come up with something relevant for your tree/soil.  These grubs are most certainly a cyclic thing and your neighbors might have had experience with these guys.  This most certainly is not just under your tree.  Please, send a few pictures, grubs and tree...?

Comment: Your logic is wonderful...most certainly could have come from the nursery but how old is this fig tree?  If it has been planted and has been growing in that spot for less than one season, maybe.  Grubs are the larval state of an insect...usually those insects grow into adults and fly away, crawl away, right away.  They don't stick around. Tell us more about this fig, how old it is, is it in a pot?  or is it in the ground?  I am so curious to get more information!!!  Your issue I doubt is localized unless you just planted this fig.  They'll be leaving soon but hate to think of the damage...

Comment: The fig tree was there for over a year before it died. I have not seen any grubs anywhere else in my yard.

Comment: So your fig tree died?

Comment: When a tree dies, anything left of that tree has to decompose.  Lots of decomposers and other opportunistic insects flock to the feast.  Those grubs are most likely part of that crowd.  Please, a picture of those grubs is bare minimum to be able to responsibly help you.  How often are you digging up soil in your yard?  Grubs are everywhere.  Lots of controls in a healthy garden; birds, nematodes, moles, voles, gophers, shrews...grubs are a yummy commodity.  If grubs get out of control it is always because we humans did something to disrupt the normal soil life killed the controls.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76225/discussion-between-geremia-and-stormy).